# Is it better to buy OTG host hub with type-C or micro type-B if I have B and C compatible devices?

Tags: usb, android

I could buy type-B USB OTG host hub like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33046931927.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4ec4720d53H2qq&algo_pvid=29840a05-7b0e-4758-9aaa-f91898b06316&algo_expid=29840a05-7b0e-4758-9aaa-f91898b06316-17&btsid=7060f49d-f395-486d-b441-ceadc83372c6&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3,searchweb201603_53) (4th selection) and type-B female/type-C male. But do I need some special adapter which supports OTG? Or maybe it's better to buy type-C OTG host hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is better to use type-C**

- As more devices are moving to type-C and you can phase out your
  adapter for type-B over time.
- Type-C also has more capabilities and you will be handicapped later
  on by converting from B to C. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C
- Your HUB does not need to specify OTG as it a standard that is
  addopted by the device your are attaching it to (IE your smartphone).
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go

Here is a USB-C hub that has worked very well for me across desktop, laptop, and smartphone: https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07GDHD3VC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

**Edit to answer comment:** 
Your first question is answered above. Your second question is answered below.

Here is an image of what you are likely to find inside the adapter: https://images.app.goo.gl/AVwQqKQCk6SfeSMj7
The unused pin you see is used to sense whether your phone should act as the host or the device. When it acts as the host you are in the OTG mode.

You could purchase a USB-B to A OTG adapter and a USB-A to C adapter but there is no guarantee that your older devices will support this. If you want to make sure both devices work, you could get 2 OTG adapters: one from B to A and one from C to A, and then use a USB-A hub.

Comment: Thanks for answer but my fault is that I didn't explain what adapter I'm talking about. If I buy Type-C HUB, I also want to buy adapter like [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-3-1-Type-C-Female-to-Micro-USB-Male-Data-Adapter-Connector-Converter-USB-C-/371979929960) but I read somewhere that Type-C cable always has OTG implemented. On micro Type-B, 1 additional pin determines if it's OTG or not. So, if I want to use Type-C HUB for micro-USB compatible device, I'd use that adapter, but my doubt is that OTG may not work through it.

Comment: Not in the scope of an answer but if it were me, I would buy the adapter you show in the above comment and try it. If it doesn't work, you just connect that unused OTG pin to the ground pin with some solder. [Diagram](https://images.app.goo.gl/gvKtY3r5gY9ihBuq9)